# How long does the "./configure make make install" code take to run?

Tags: openexr

I am trying to built an OpenEXR library in Windows visual studio 2017. First I have to build ilmbase (version 2.3.0). 
I put "./configure" in as code in windows visual studio and have it running.
It has been running for almost 2 hours now. The diagnostic tools indicate that the process memory is running constantly at 60 MB and there is 0 CPU. 
I have no experience programming and only little experience in MATLAB, so I am wondering whether I have done the right thing and whether running the "./configure" code should take that long to run.